# Why doesn't R documentation specify required packages?

Tags: r, package

Scenario: I'm following an tutorial in a YouTube video. When I invoke the function "glimpse", I get a `could not find function "glimpse"`error. So I say, `?glimpse` and RTFM that tells me a description, Usage, Arguments, etc. But doesn't mention anywhere that it is part of the dplyr package. Obviously, I figured it out, but this seems like such a glaring omission that I'm tempted to believe there is some good reason for it. Is there?

Thanks,
Tup

Comment: If you use `?glimpse` in R to read the documentation, the  package is listed on the top of the  help window. You can also search for functions in https://www.rdocumentation.org to find what package it could be from

Comment: This seems odd because `?` should only bring up the help page for loaded packages. The `??` function searches all installed packages. Are you sure you didn't use the latter? But as pointed out, the package name is in the top left corner of the help page in braces. You can usually scroll all the way to the bottom of the help page as well to see the package name.

Comment: Hmm. Assuming that my problem was caused by an unloaded package, I googled "glimpse package".It was rdocumentation.org that reported:  "    is part of dplyr package so first activiate dplyr package and then run glimpse function." I did and the problem went away. "Installed.packages" now tells that both dplyr and tibble are installed, but I did not knowingly install tibble. 

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.3/topics/glimpse

Comment: The `glimpse` function is part of the `tibble` package, which is one of the dependencies of `dplyr`. You can't load current versions of `dplyr` without also loading `tibble`, since it relies on those functions (like `glimpse`) extensively.  See https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/DESCRIPTION